# how to create a gradient color in elevated button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, linear-gradients

I trying to create a gradient button in flutter but in `ElevatedButton` shows some shadow or its strucuture there even when the color was set to transparent.

Here I have used `DecoratedBox` for applying gradient color is there any way to apply gradient in `ElevatedButton`?

The Code I have used

```
               child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.blue,
                    ],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  )),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        //     builder: (BuildContext context) => RegisterScreen()));
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.transparent,
                          onPrimary: Colors.transparent),
                      child: Text(
                        "Register",
                        style: TextManager.btnText,
                      )),
                ),
```

by setting elevation to 0 resolved but when I click the button the thing is also visible. Setting splash color to transparent also didn't work.

The output button is here

[image]

Comment: I guess providing `elevation` parameter's value to 0 will solve your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply wrap your `child` property with an `Ink` widget. By doing so you will be able to apply a gradient and keep the elevated effect from the button.

### Code Sample

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        elevation: 5,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Ink(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.cyan]),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 88.0),
          child: const Text('OK', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

[Try the full test code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/63b4de1da057674fd50e51a24cba6ddc?null_safety=true)